# AWS X-Ray Trace ID Root not set when invoking Lambda from another Lambda function in Node.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-xray

I have `X-Ray` cofnigured and it works for most of the system but having issue when invoking a `Lambda` from another `Lambda`. I am wrapping whole `aws` SDK before calling `new Lambda()`:

```
import xray from 'aws-xray-sdk-core';
import aws from 'aws-sdk';

const awsXray = xray.captureAWS(aws);
const lambda = new awsXray.Lambda();
const response = await lambda.invoke({...}).promise();
```

Similar approach works for other services but with this invocation, the `Lambda` that is being invoked has always `Trace ID` root set to `Root=1-00000000-000000000000000000000000`

I have tried also wrapping an instance as:
`const lambda = captureAWSClient(new aws.Lambda());` but this did not help. The lambda that is invoking (code above) has `Trace ID` correctly set.

Comment: Can you confirm if the second lambda has Tracing enabled. Also add the specific versions of `aws-xray-sdk-core`, `aws-sdk` and your lambda runtime.

Answer (score 0):

That is the Root trace ID set if your trace is unsampled. Because it is unsampled it will not be sent to the X-Ray service so the trace ID value is irrelevant, and not generated to save performance. To get valid trace ID values, you should adjust your [sampling rules in the X-Ray console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console-sampling.html) and ensure active tracing is enabled on your Lambda.